# Django test client gets 301 redirection when accessing url

Tags: ajax, django, post, django-testing

I am writing unittests for django views. I have observed that one of my views returns redirection code 301, which is not expected.
Here is my views.py mentioned earlier.

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html',
                  {'form': QueryForm()})

def query(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        form = QueryForm(request.POST)
        return HttpResponse('valid')
```

Below is urls.py.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
         url(r'^$', 'core.views.index'),
         url(r'^query/$', 'core.views.query')
         )
```

And unittest that will fail.

```
def so_test(self):
    response = self.client.post('/')
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)

    response = self.client.post('/query', {})
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

My question is: why there is status 301 returned?

Comment: Which one is returning 301? Is that the full code?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Second one, sorry that it was not clear.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have defined a url that matches `/query/`, but you are testing `/query`. Django is redirecting to the url with the trailing slash because [`APPEND_SLASH=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) in your settings.

You probably want to change your test to:

```
response = self.client.post('/query/', {})
```

Answer (score 12):

For me, the problem was that I mistakenly ran the tests with a `setting.py` file that had [`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True`](https://django-secure.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.1/settings.html#secure-ssl-redirect). Changing to `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False` solved the issue.

Another option is to use the `client` with `secure=True`, i.e.:

```
response = self.client.post('/query/', {}, secure=True)
```

which will make the client [emulate an HTTPS request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.post).