# Django Test Case gets diffrent redirect than Firefox or Chrome

Tags: python, django, django-testing

Trying to work on a project and get my head around unit Testing.
I'm confused why client.get is getting a diffrent redirect than both Firefox and Chrome.

Details below, but can someone give me an idea this is occuring.

- Django Version 3
- Python verson 3.8
- Running on Ubuntu in WSL in windows.

My View Function.

```
class UserDashboardView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/login')
```

My Test Case

```
import unittest
from django.test import TestCase

class DashboardPageTest(TestCase):

    def test_unauthenticated_user_redirected_to_login(self):
        response = self.client.get('/dashboard')
        print(response)
```

What occurs.

1 - If I go to /dashboard in Chrome and Firefox the debug shows a 302 with a location key of /accounts/login, and so the browser follows to /accounts/login

2 - If I run the unit test (python manage.py test) the print of the response returns

```
<HttpResponsePermanentRedirect status_code=301, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/dashboard/">
```

I have a feeling their is something I just don't get about the way the browsers vs the TestCase does redirects. Can someone please explain it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed out trailing slash in your unit test, so it is redirecting from `/dashboard` to `/dashboard/`.

Comment: Yep just found this out too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.
Found the solution at [Django test client gets 301 redirection when accessing url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784905/django-test-client-gets-301-redirection-when-accessing-url)

Basically Django was being helpfull and adding a / to the end of the request. Thus it was sending back a permanet redirect to let me know. Chrome and firefox must have dealt with it 
Changed the line in the test case to

response = self.client.get('/dashboard/') instead of response = self.client.get('/dashboard') and it returns 302. And now that I look at the browsers I was going to /dashboard/ in the browsers.

Comment: If you go to `/dashboard` in your browser, it will follow the 301 redirect to `/dashboard/` then the 302 redirect to `/accounts/login`. The [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get) doesn't follow the redirects because `follow=False` by default.